# Date to Timestamp with UTC in Java

Tags: java, date-conversion

I have to convert a date (that is already in UTC) to a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

#### Issue

But when doing that, the time is changed to machine time:

```java
new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

So I get another date on the server.

#### Expected

When I convert back to `Date` I want to have the same date as before conversion.
I want to keep the same date (in UTC).

How could I do that?

Comment: Can you please post your code? I mean the one that changed the time…

Comment: Please stay away from those outdated legacy classes. Use the classes from `java.time` instead and your life will be easier (`Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDateTime`, ...).

Comment: Your terminology is kinda off. Please share your real code and elaborate on the situation. Downvoted because unclear, voting to close because needs details.

Answer (score 2):

It does not change the time. `Timestamp` and `Date` don't have a concept of a timezone, they represent an instant of time since the Epoch(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

Their `.toString()` methods on the other hand, have the bad habit of applying the default timezone of the JVM, when generating the string representation. I would advise to stay away from those classes, and instead use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the modern java datetime API, it's available since java 8.

Comment: Maybe interesting to mention, there is a backport of the API to also make it available to versions prior to Java 8.

Comment: The ".getTime" method is the problem, that looks for the machine's timezone